# Is there any way to play Unity games that were released as only a .exe have not been updated to include a UnityPlayer.dll in the download?

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10

I don't know if this is the right place for this question, though if it isn't, I'd kindly ask you to redirect me to where I can ask it.

I need to play an obscure small-scale indie game called Offbeat for a school project. It's at https://gameheads.itch.io/offbeat. But when I downloaded the files and clicked on the offbeatv2Windows.exe file in the game folder it gives an error saying that UnityPlayer.dll could not be found. I found that in newer versions of Unity the game build is split into the .exe and data folder for the game and the UnityPlayer.dll file for the engine, so both of them need to be included in the download for the game to run. But the creator of this game has moved on and hasn't added it to the download so I can't play it. Downloading a UnityPlayer.dll file from the internet just gave a different error. Could anyone tell me if it is in any way possible for me to play the game?

Answer (score 1):

## You can't; it's impossible.

All standalone Unity executables always come with a `XXX_data` (assuming the executable is `XXX.exe`, and replace `XXX` with the name of the game).

I've looked at the game download files and the folder/executable pair is there. Did you maybe incorrectly extracted the zip file?

[image]

Comment: I got both the folder and the executable, but when I try to run the .exe it gives me that "UnityPlayer.dll cannot be found" error. Does it run for you?

Comment: Try building an empty with the exact same Unity version (assuming you can figure out which) and then copy over your `UnityPlayer.dll`. Assuming, you can figure out which version. Also, fyi, we're approaching off-topic scopes for this site.